# In R, pull out a value from a dataframe with the given row and column index for another dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

I have this mapping table,

```
df <- data.frame(fli.1 = c(0, 700, 1500, 2000, 3500, 5600, 11000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.2 = c(0, 200, 1000, 2900, 3000, 5500, 10000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.3 = c(0, 600, 1200, 2500, 3900, 5000, 10000, 22000, 58000),
                 fli.4 = c(0, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 14000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.5 = c(0, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000))
```

and another dataframe which is

```
d <- data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6, 4, 2, 4, 7, 1, 1), fli = c("fli.1", "fli.1", "fli.4", "fli.5", "fli.2", "fli.2", "fli.5", "fli.1", "fli.2", "fli.2", "fli.3", "fli.4"));
```

I need to create an additional column in the dataframe d which picks the value from dataframe df with the given row and column index in dataframe d.
row in the d given the index of row in df and fli in d gives index of column in df.

and solution should look like this 0,700,3000, ...

this is just a demonstration i need to apply it to very large dataset. i.e. d dataframe is around one million.

Comment: what have you edited @MrFlick

Comment: if you click the "edited X mins ago" link you will see a side-by-side comparison before and after edits. Looks like MrFlick removed the `rstudio` tag, which makes sense because that tag should be reserved for RStudio-related problems, such as if you have code that works using R from the command line but doesn't work in RStudio.

Comment: do you have a solution Gregor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index a matrix using another matrix of row/column indices - so we can convert `df` to a matrix, find the column numbers that go with the row numbers, and use that:

```
d$col = match(d$fli, names(df))
d$result = as.matrix(df)[as.matrix(d[c("row", "col")])]
d
#    row   fli col result
# 1    1 fli.1   1      0
# 2    2 fli.1   1    700
# 3    5 fli.4   4   3000
# 4    5 fli.5   5   3500
# 5    4 fli.2   2   2900
# 6    6 fli.2   2   5500
# 7    4 fli.5   5   2000
# 8    2 fli.1   1    700
# 9    4 fli.2   2   2900
# 10   7 fli.2   2  10000
# 11   1 fli.3   3      0
# 12   1 fli.4   4      0
```

The other way I can think to do this would be to loop over each column and fill in a results vector in batches:

```
each_fli = unique(d$fli)
result = numeric(length = nrow(d))
for(i in each_fli) {
  idx = which(d$fli == i)
  result[idx] = df[[i]][d$row[idx]]
}
d$result = result
#   row   fli result
# 1    1 fli.1      0
# 2    2 fli.1    700
# 3    5 fli.4   3000
# 4    5 fli.5   3500
# 5    4 fli.2   2900
# 6    6 fli.2   5500
# 7    4 fli.5   2000
# 8    2 fli.1    700
# 9    4 fli.2   2900
# 10   7 fli.2  10000
# 11   1 fli.3      0
# 12   1 fli.4      0
```

Unfortunately, on a fairly large sample, this is a little bit slower than the matrix conversion, even if we convert the `df` object to a `data.table` beforehand.

Here are the benchmark results (and the code follows):

```
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# 1 matrix_conversion   9.42ms   16.1ms      58.3    11.3MB     19.4    18     6      309ms <int> 
# 2 loop_df            19.76ms   22.8ms      34.0    11.4MB     12.4    11     4      324ms <int> 
# 3 loop_dt            19.62ms   20.7ms      47.3    11.4MB     14.8    16     5      338ms <int> 
# # ℹ 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>

library(data.table)
nc = 26
nr = 1e5
big_df = replicate(nc, rpois(nr, lambda = 100)) |> as.data.frame() |> setNames(letters)
big_dt = as.data.table(big_df)
big_d = data.frame(
  row = sample(nr, size = 5e4, replace = TRUE), 
  fli = sample(letters, size = 5e4, replace = TRUE)
)

bench::mark(
  matrix_conversion = {
    big_d$col = match(big_d$fli, names(big_df))
    as.matrix(big_df)[as.matrix(big_d[c("row", "col")])]
  },
  
  loop_df = {
    each_fli = unique(big_d$fli)
    result = integer(length = nrow(big_d))
    for(i in each_fli) {
      idx = which(big_d$fli == i)
      result[idx] = big_df[[i]][big_d$row[idx]]
    }
    result
  },

  loop_dt = {
    each_fli = unique(big_d$fli)
    result = integer(length = nrow(big_d))
    for(i in each_fli) {
      idx = which(big_d$fli == i)
      result[idx] = big_dt[[i]][big_d$row[idx]]
    }
    result
  }
)
```

Comment: this takes time, i have been doing using mapply but both ways by matrix or mapply takes time to perform. I was looking something using datatable.

Comment: If you mean the `data.table` R package, then I would suggest editing your question (a) so that your example code creates a `data.table` object, not a `data.frame`, and (b) edit your tag to be `data.table` (notice the `.`), you'll see the tag descriptors are different.